# Drupal wysiwyg menu not showing

Tags: drupal-7

Drupal 7, wysiwyg module with the ckeditor library installed. The text formats are configured. I have used and set up this module/editor configuration various times with no problems, so I'm baffled.

In this case there is simply no editor showing at all in the content creation pages, just the default text box.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say 'configured' does that also mean you've configured the relevant permissions?

Comment: Clive, what would those relevant permissions be?  There is no permission associated with the WYSIWYG module, nor the CCKEditor. So I guess to answer your question no, I have not configured the relevant permissions, but I sure would like to. Suggestions?

Comment: No, this issue is not resolved.

Comment: Is there anyone there?

Answer (score 2):

Kind of late to the party, but I just faced this issue and managed to solve.

What i did was:
1) Go to /admin/config/content/wysiwyg
2) for each entry under "text format" I clicked edit.
3) expanded "Show Buttons and plugins" and checked all of them
4) cick save

Worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is having this issue - I just managed to fix it for a role by allowing them to view the admin theme

Answer (score 1):

I had a simular problem. All the answers I found previously did not help me.

The solution for me was the following: disable the "Aggregate JavaScript files." option!

You can find this option under: Configuration -> Development -> Performance

I hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but here the wysiwyg menu was not showing only for one of my content types.
I have de JQuery Update module installed. The problem was solved when I went to /admin/config/development/jquery_update and changed the Default JQuery version for administrative pages from 1.7 to 1.10.

Answer (score 0):

It was working fine for me. Let me describe the working example.

1) Download drupal 7 [wysiwyg](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module

2) Go to [CKEditor download](http://ckeditor.com/download)  or else [v3.5.3](http://ckeditor.com/release/ckeditor-353) .Please only download version 3.5.3   because other versions may be giving problem. (Read it more from [here](http://drupal.org/node/1161738))

3) After downloading the editor library, put it into sites\all\libraries\ckeditor .

4) Goto -> admin -> configuration -> Wysiwyg profiles

if you placed library correctly into " sites\all\libraries\ckeditor ", then you can see the edit options.

According to your need set the options.

5) Go to content creation area, here you can find your result based upon your setting.

ie, if you enabled it for Full html text format, it will be available only when you set text format as Full Html.

[image]

Please see the attached image for more help.

Comment: Thanks kalidasan, but this didn't help me in my situation. It will be useful for those that need help with installing the module however.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to disable the menu that is created inside the node editing if this option is checked, save your node without this option and see if it works