# Drupal - editor not showing and unable to edit WYSIWYG editor profile

Tags: drupal, tinymce, editor

I am currently trying to get Drupal to work on my Arch Linux system. Everything was going fine until I tried to install and configure the WYSIWYG editor timymce along with the WYSIWG module itself. I have placed the module in the correct folder (i.e. sites/all/libraries) and set the permissions to 755 (for non-Linux guys, this is basically user - rwx, group - rx, other rx). It shows up on the WYSIWYG profile page - I can save it as "Filtered HTML" etc - but when I try to edit it, I am directed to the editing page, but the links to actually edit - i.e. the links (e.g. "Basic Set Up", "Buttons and Plugins" etc. ) appear to be dead - I click on them and nothing happens. Also, the editor is not displaying when I click on add content. I don't get how I can select the actual editor on the WYSIWYG profile page, but can't edit the profile and the actual editor doesn't show.

I have looked all over the web for an answer - for example below:

[Drupal wysiwyg menu not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219303/drupal-wysiwyg-menu-not-showing)

...but nothing appears to be completely specific to my issue because I can select the editor but not edit it or see it when I try to edit a basic page.

I think it barely needs saying that I am a Drupal novice - in fact this is my first day with it - but I would very much appreciate any advice from a Drupal guru on how to get this going. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I have the bootstrap theme installed and I had to also include the JQuery_update module to update JQuery to a more recent version - the links now work and I am able to configure my editor.